# Render.com: Cookie not begin set in browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, render.com

I have Deployed my Node.js project on render.com, Everthing is working fine when I run my project on localsystem but I got the issue related cookie on my deployed node.js.

When I hit /login then I got the success message but the cookie is not store in browser.

I am using passport.local for authentication. When I hit '/login' I got the success message that "User is loggedIn" but afterwards when I hit any route that is checking user is authenticated or not as middleware then I got the 401 Unauthorized response.

This is how I managed cookie from backend.

```
app.use(session({
    name: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: 'None',
        secure: true,
    }
}));
```

I have already passed the frontend url in CORS:

```
router.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://frontend-datuni.onrender.com',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
 }));
```

These are the link where my project is running:

Server/Backend: https://backend-ioyu.onrender.com

Client/Frontend: https://frontend-datuni.onrender.com

[Network section scrrenshot of /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCmhv.png)
[Network section scrrenshot of /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE0eP.png)
[Network section scrrenshot of /mydetail (Auth required for the request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W805p.png)
[Network section scrrenshot of /mydetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThOm.png)

I have tried to change the value of app.use(session).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.